# How do I create a dictionary in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create a config from a template using ansible which should look like this

```yaml
files:
  '/opt/services':
    box 1:
      url: localhost:5623
    box 2:
      url: localhost:5623
    box 3:
      url: localhost:5623
```

I have a variable `{{ box_names }}` which gives `["box 1", "box 2", "box 3", and so on]`

rn my task looks like this

```yaml
tasks:
- name: print the box names
  debug:
    msg: "box names: {{ box_names }}"

- name: Settings | Import default config    
  template:
    src: test.yaml.j2
    dest: "/opt/test/config.yaml"
    owner: "{{ user.name }}"
    group: "{{ user.name }}"
    mode: 0775
  loop: "{{ box_names }}"
```

and my config template looks like

```yaml
files:
  '/opt/services':
    {{ item }}:
           url: localhost:5623
```

but the final template only shows box 1 and not box 2 or box 3. how do I make the config show all the items of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

use the loop inside the template j2 file:

```
files:
  '/opt/services':
    {% for box in box_names %}
    {{box}}:
           url: localhost:5623
    {% endfor %}
```

The task:

```
- name: Settings | Import default config    
  template:
    src: test.yaml.j2
    dest: "/opt/test/config.yaml"
    owner: "{{ user.name }}"
    group: "{{ user.name }}"
    mode: 0775
```

result:

```
files:
  '/opt/services':
        box 1:
           url: localhost:5623
        box 2:
           url: localhost:5623
        box 3:
           url: localhost:5623
```

if you want ot use this result as var file, i suggest you to add quotes around key in the template file

Answer (score 0):

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  files:
    /opt/services: "{{ dict(box_names|
                            product([{'url': 'localhost:5623'}])) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  files:
    /opt/services:
      box 1:
        url: localhost:5623
      box 2:
        url: localhost:5623
      box 3:
        url: localhost:5623
```

Then, the template is trivial

```yaml
shell> cat test.yaml.j2
files:
  {{ files|to_nice_yaml }}
```